# Macbook Pro 15" 2017 bluetooth reconnects when mouse is connected

Tags: macbook-pro, bluetooth

I have a Macbook Pro 15" 2017 and it keeps dropping and restoring Bluetooth connection when a mouse is connected to it. It never happens when only the keyboard is connected happens every several minutes or so when only the mouse is connected and happens like every minute when the keyboard and the mouse are both connected.

When this reconnection occurs, both devices are reconnected, not only the mouse.

Actually, if the mouse IS connected, but not used, this doesn't happen.

Here are the logs from Bluetooth Explorer (I don't know what might be relevant and what not):

```
2020-10-19 12:45:36 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:45:36 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-10-19 12:46:07 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:46:07 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
Oct 19 14:47:34 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.19029): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.TCPRelayService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
Oct 19 14:47:35 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.19029): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/IDETouchBarSimulatorService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex

Oct 19 14:47:37 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.19029): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/RootDebuggingXPCService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex

2020-10-19 12:47:38 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:47:38 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
Oct 19 14:47:44 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.19029): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEOSXSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.dt.XcodeMacLocationSimulation.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex

2020-10-19 12:47:47 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:47:47 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-10-19 12:47:47 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:47:47 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-10-19 12:48:02 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:48:02 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-10-19 12:48:36 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:48:36 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-10-19 12:48:44 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:48:45 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
68-fe-f7-3d-ad-59 connected, handle: 0x41
2020-10-19 12:48:51 +0000 Handle: 0x41 disconnected, reason: 0x16
Apple Watch — Konstantin disconnected
2020-10-19 12:49:07 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:49:07 +0000 Mode change 11 for handle: 0x2
2020-10-19 12:49:19 +0000 Handle: 0xB disconnected, reason: 0x08
Razer Orochi disconnected
2020-10-19 12:49:20 +0000 Role change 0 for handle: 0x0
Razer Orochi connected, handle: 0xD
2020-10-19 12:49:20 +0000 Mode change 13 for handle: 0x2
Oct 19 14:49:22 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.0F000000-0300-0000-0000-000000000000[20547]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[155]
Oct 19 14:49:23 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.activateSettings.21396): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Versions/A/Resources/activateSettings, error = 2: No such file or directory

2020-10-19 12:49:45 +0000 Mode change 13 for handle: 0x0
2020-10-19 12:49:46 +0000 Mode change 13 for handle: 0x2
Oct 19 14:50:00 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.21793): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.TCPRelayService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex

Oct 19 14:50:01 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.06000000-0400-0000-0000-000000000000[21371]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[155]
Oct 19 14:50:02 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.21793): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/IDETouchBarSimulatorService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex

Oct 19 14:50:04 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.21793): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/RootDebuggingXPCService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex

Oct 19 14:50:13 mbp-konstantin com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.21793): Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/IDEOSXSupportCore.ideplugin/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.dt.XcodeMacLocationSimulation.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
```

I have already tried this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251251648
Both file deletion and device removal. And of course, NVRAM PRAM reset. Don't really know what else can I do. I can buy another mouse, but I'm afraid this can be not its fault.

Please help me to fix this. It is very annoying and just kills productivity.

Here's the configuration of my MacBook:
[image]

Comment: Why can't this issue be caused by the mouse? Buy a BT mouse from a place with a good return policy and try this with the new mouse.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Catalina. The culprit was the mouse.

Comment: I was doubting that the mouse was the cause of the problem because all connected devices were reconnecting. But now I think it might be it.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I've been plagued by issues with bluetooth connections, I've since switched to a wired keyboard and I'm trialing different devices for both headset and mouse, including a Logitech M720 Triathlon, Bose QC35, Microsoft Generation 1 Surface Headphones, and a mighty mouse. The drop outs are always accompanied with the following error message.

com.apple.xpc.launchd[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqNp1.png) (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.activateSettings.61274): Failed to bootstrap path: path = /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/Versions/A/Resources/activateSettings, error = 2: No such file or directory

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It's difficult to understand how this answers the OP's question.